# How to account for exceptions in Vb.Net Linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, exception

I'm not sure how Linq will react if it tries to execute statements on empty results. I found the FirstOrDefault() method in the docs, but then there is OrderByDescending() which could cause an exception to occur if the results are empty? The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976(v=vs.110).aspx) state that First() would throw an exception, so what about the others? Is the following code safe from exceptions?

```
Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(path)
Dim lastfile As FileInfo

If di.Exists Then
    lastfile = di.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly) _
    .Where(Function(f) f.Length > 20000) _
    .OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTime) _
    .FirstOrDefault(Nothing)

    If Not IsNothing(lastfile) Then
        'Work with file here and hopefully not throw an exception.
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `GetFiles()` function may throw exceptions, so the code is not safe from exception.

However, if your question is strictly about the LINQ code aside from the `GetFiles()` function then it is safe because the `GetFiles()` either returns a list of files or an empty list if no files found. In the case of empty list, the LINQ functions that you have will work and not throw exceptions.

From [MSDN DirectoryInfo.GetFiles Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8he88b63(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If there are no files in the DirectoryInfo, this method returns an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the documentation calls out any exceptions. Sorting an empty sequence is not a problem because an empty sequence is always sorted. No exception will happen. You are safe.

Think like an API designer: Why would you make `OrderBy` or `Where` throw for empty sequences? There is no reason.